# Python mongodb unset key with nested value

Tags: python, mongodb

I have the following code that drops a key `item` successfully:

```
get_image.update(unset__item=1)
```

This drops the key `item`. However, I would like this only to drop when item has a field `promotion` that is set to `true`:

```
"item" : [
   {
      "promotion" : "true
   }

]
```

is there any way to check this using `unset`?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick.

```py
collection.update_many({ “item”: { “promotion”: True }, { “$unset”: { “item”: 1 } })
```

Alternatively, if you’re trying to delete all documents which have a `true` `promotion` field:

```py
collection.delete_many({ “item”: { “promotion”: True } })
```